# How to push an array inside another array element as a new property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

So, 
For instance, I have the following array

```
var sections = [{ name: 'apple', count: 20 },
                 { name: 'banana', count: 80 },
                 { name: 'oranges', count: 10 }]
```

Now, if I want to add more items, then I can do

```
sections.push({ name: 'mango', count: '32' });
```

which will add the new array to sections.

Now, suppose, I have another array that shows where the fruit came from and how many.

```
var country = [{ country: 'usa', count: 5 },
               { country: 'brazil', count: 27 }]
```

So, I want to add this new `country` array to the third element of `sections` with a new prop called country as the following.

```
var sections = [{ name: 'apple', count: 20 },
                { name: 'banana', count: 80 },
                { name: 'oranges', count: 10,
                  country: [{ country: 'usa', count: 5 },
                            { country: 'brazil', count: 27 }]
                }]
```

How can I do this? I tried `push`, `splice` but couldn't figure it out at all.

I also tried sections[3].push.apply(country).. and many other things that I can't recall anymore. Either I received an error or just didn't push the array as I wanted to.

Comment: `sections[2].country = country`;

Comment: Really??!!!!. It's that easy? And I was trying all the other difficult ways in the world?? Gosh!!! 
Thanks

Comment: Does "another array" index positions correspond to `sections` array index positions ?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but the answers I got are all correct answers.

Comment: @user1828605 Yes . `sections` contains 3 items . Does "another array"  contain 3 items corresponding to `section` items ?

Comment: It doesn't have to. The array that I'm working on has 18 items, and each item contains at least 3 items. However, based on the name, it dynamically adds "another array" which could be 1 or 1000 as long as the count of each item is greater than 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
sections[2].country =  country;
```

Here, writing `sections[2]` we peek a reference to the third item of the `sections`. Then we define a property called `country` and we assign to it the value we want.

Why push didn't work?

The push is an array method, that gives you the ability to push an element at the end of an array. If you try to make use of push on `sections[2]` will not work, since `sections[2]` is not an array. The same holds for the `splice`, it's an array method.

Answer (score 1):

`push` is for adding to an array, not for adding properties to an object. For a property, just assign the property name.

```
sections[2].country = country;
```

If the property already existed and you wanted to add to it, you would use `push` as follows:

```
section[2].country.push({country: 'venezuela', count: 20});
```

And don't forget that array indexes start at `0`, so the third element is `[2]`.